# An anonymous function in a php library is incompatible with php 5.2

Tags: php

How can I convert the following anonymous function, found in a php library I am using, to be compatible with php 5.2 (which does not support anonymous functions):

```
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($handle, $data) use (&$headers, &$body, &$header_length, $max_data_length) {
        $body .= $data;

        if ($headers == '') {
            $headers_end = strpos($body, "\r\n\r\n");
            if ($headers_end !== false) {
                $header_length = $headers_end;
                $headers = substr($body, 0, $header_length);
                $body = substr($body, $header_length + 4);


                # Now that we have headers, if the content type is not HTML, we do
                # not need to download anything else. Prevents us from downloading
                # images, videos, PDFs, etc. that won't contain redirects

                # Until PHP 5.4, you can't import $this lexical variable into a closure,
                # so we will need to duplicate code from contentTypeFromHeader()
                # and hasHTMLContentType()
                if (preg_match('/^\s*Content-Type:\s*([^\s;\n]+)/im', $headers, $matches)) {
                    if (stripos($matches[1], 'html') === false) { return 0; }
                }
            }
        }

        # If we have downloaded the maximum amount of content, we're done.
        if (($header_length + strlen($body)) > $max_data_length) { return 0; }

        return strlen($data);
    });
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to convert the anonymous function to a named function and reference it in the `curl_setopt` call, approximately thus:

```
function curl_writefunction_callback($handle, $data) {
  global $headers;
  global $body;
  global $header_length;
  global $max_data_length;
  # [function body here]
};

curl_setopt($curl, CURL_WRITEFUNCTION, "curl_writefunction_callback");
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I thought, but the "use" part of the anonymous function is confusing me, not sure how that will go with said named function:
function($handle, $data) use (&$headers, &$body, &$header_length, $max_data_length) {

Comment: @MartinS `use`, in PHP's disastrous excuse for lambda functions, is the equivalent of `global` in named functions, and can be translated as such. I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: It's not equivalent. `use` imports variable from it's definition scope, `global` is limited to global scope, so if you want to access results stored in these variables, you have to declare them global in your scope.

Comment: @dev-null-dweller Seriously, PHP tries at last to figure out something remotely resembling lexical scoping, and it ends up with *that*? That's not even wrong, and in light of it, I'm really not sure what to suggest at this point.

Comment: in 5.2 I was using objects with one method (callback) and public properties, just to avoid global scope.